# Selecting a body for a sleeper

Tags: body

More specifically how do you determine whether a car's chassis can support the weight of aftermarket parts when building a sleeper.

For example can you fit a v8 into a car that originally had an inline-4 engine?

Comment: Specifically, what do you want to do? I mean, there are [plenty of v8 Samurai's](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=v8+in+a+samurai) out there. If there's a will, there's a way. It ALWAYS depends on how much money, time, & effort you are willing to put into the project.

Comment: I dont wanna do anything just yet. I just want to know if its possible to fit a really huge engine into a really small car. 
Cos I'm assuming that the engine(and other parts) might fall out of the car if the chassis isnt strong enough.

Comment: Seen a large V8 fitted into a Morris Minor... That is large into small - but oh boy did it go...

Comment: I wanna build a w16 sleeper with a BMW E46 M3 someday. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have done a 4 cyl to V8 conversion, so it is possible, your choice of donor vehicle will define how many conversion issues you will face.

You need to have a thorough understanding of all that needs to be done. Such as cooling system upgrade, power steering, brake upgrades, exhaust system (welding possibly necessary) transmission (clutch /flywheel and adaptor plates), making engine mounts, making (extending or shortening) propshafts, moving or re-building chassis members and sorting the wiring /computer issues.

Solving the issues is challenging and a great learning experience.